# How to hide keyboard in iOS app using frida?

Tags: javascript, ios, frida

I am new to using frida with ios Application, I have a lot of questions regarding that issue, if anyone could provide me with some book or articles to read in order to get better at it.

My current problem is I'm trying to hide the keyboard in an iOS App using frida, I am trying the following code as far I understood how the iOS apps are working:

```
var firstResponder = ObjC.classes.UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow().firstResponder();


if (firstResponder.isNull() || !firstResponder.isKindOfClass_(ObjC.classes.UIView)) {
  console.log("Error: first responder is not a UIView");
 
}


firstResponder.resignFirstResponder();
```

But this code is making the app crash. Can anyone provide me with an explanation and how to achieve my goal ?

Thanks.

Comment: The first line will be calling the view being edited, I didn't understand what you mean by "many methods calls".

Comment: The chain you mentioned works perfectly, The error is not there.

Comment: Do you have an ObjC or swift code snippet you are trying to reimplements in Frida or where does the code come from you posted above? If you got the code from an internet resource you should add the link in your question so it would be easier to understand what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely crashing because in Obj-C, all UI operations should be performed on the main queue (since the UI operations are not thread safe). Try this:

```
ObjC.schedule(ObjC.mainQueue, function() {
    const firstResponder = ObjC.classes.UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow().firstResponder();
    
    if (firstResponder.isNull() || !firstResponder.isKindOfClass_(ObjC.classes.UIView)) {
        console.log("Error: first responder is not a UIView");
    } else {
        firstResponder.resignFirstResponder();
    }
});
```